# Php get today articles only?

Tags: mysql, php

i need to create a function that will display the articles of the current date only.
Here is what i have created:

```
function lastnews () {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string ($id);
    $date = date('d');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE  post_status = "publish" AND post_date = "$date"  ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 3';
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


    $title = $row['post_title'];
    echo '<li><a href="post.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$title.'</a></li>';    
}
    endif;

} // end
```

But this is not working. the formt of date in database is :

```
Y-m-d H:i
```

Thank you for reading this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the entire date (`date('Y-m-d')`) and the query should say `AND post_date > '$date'` because it includes a time.  You can also say `AND post_date > CURRENT_DATE`.

Comment: That was fast. I was thinking the same, but checking the syntax :-( - Was going to suggest this aswell: `... LIKE '_$date_%'` .

Answer (score 1):

Change 
$date = date('d');

To:
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');